# Is the following series involving $\zeta(s)$ asymptotic to $\frac{1}{2s}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, asymptotics, riemann-zeta

**Context:**

While working on [Keiper's](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5f4e/b4f19a02aab5964480b47fefdcd2c5b75968.pdf?_ga=2.178874020.1023124787.1609853889-468809419.1609694575)  $\tau_s$-function, I found that it could be split into a smooth first term and an oscillating second term:

$$\tau_s=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( {s+k-1\choose k-1}\cdot \frac{\zeta(k+1)}{(-2)^{k+1}}- {-s+k-1\choose k-1} \sigma_{k+1}^*\right)$$

with $\sigma_k^*$ defined [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/374643/is-there-a-connection-between-the-sequence-of-a-finite-number-of-stieltjes-const). I found that numerically the first term appears asymptotic to $\dfrac{1}{2s}$ for $\Re(s) \gt 0$.

**Question:**

With $s \in \mathbb{C}, \Re(s) > 0$, is the following asymptotic true ?

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {s+k-1\choose k-1}\cdot \frac{\zeta(k+1)}{(-2)^{k+1}}\asymp \frac{1}{2s} \qquad \text{for} \quad \Re(s) \rightarrow \infty$$

Comment: Numerically this appears to be true. Where did you find this?

Comment: @K.defaoite I have updated the question with the context. See also this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380869/a-hadamard-product-representation-for-keipers-tau-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use
$${n+\alpha\choose n} = (-1)^n {-\alpha-1\choose n}$$
Then
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {s+k\choose k}\frac{\zeta(k+2)}{(-2)^{k+2}} = \sum_{n\ge 1} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {-s-1\choose k} (2n)^{-k-2} = \sum_{n\ge 1}(2n)^{-2}(1+\frac1{2n})^{-s-1}$$ $$\sim \frac12 \int_1^\infty x^{-2} (1+\frac1{x})^{-s-1}dx=\frac12 \int_0^1 (1+y)^{-s-1}dy=\frac{1-2^{-s}}{2s}$$